# Cassandra backup to tape or real snapshots

Tags: cassandra, backup, snapshot

Is there a way to backup Cassandra directly to tape (streaming device)?
Or to perform real snapshots?
The snapshot Cassandra is referring to is not what I want to call a snapshot. 
It is more a consistent copy of the database files to a directory.

Regards Tomas

Answer (score 2):

First, let's clarify the Cassandra write path, so we know what we need to back up. Writes come in and are first journaled in the commitlog, then written to the memtable, then eventually flushed to sstables. When sstables flush, the relevant commitlog segments are deleted.

If you want a consistent backup of Cassandra, you need at the very least the sstables, but ideally the sstables + commitlog, so you can replay any data between the commitlog and the most recent flush.

If you're using tape backup, you can treat the files on disk (both commitlog and sstables) as typical data files - you can tar them, rsync them, copy them as needed, or point amanda or whatever tape system you're using at the data file directory + commitlog directory, and it should just work - there's not a lot of magic there, just grab them and back them up. One of the more common backup processes involves using [tablesnap](https://github.com/JeremyGrosser/tablesnap), which watches for new sstables and uploads them to s3.

Comment: The problem is how to grab all the spreaded snapshot files in to one single location in order to make the tar file .

Comment: You would backup each directory on each server independently. If you're unable to do that, you'd need a central server connected to tape to stage it, and it'd have to be quite large.

Comment: No . My question is suppose i have a one node cluster. So all the data reside in the server it self. When i take a snapshot i cant get a single file. Or those files not in a single location. My goal is to take all the files realated to the single snapshot and tar it and store it in a separate network file system. But i couldnt find a way to grab all the table level snapshot files to one single location in order to tar them. Is there anyway for that?

Comment: Cassandra in its current form always snapshots to a directory within the data directory, nested beneath the live data, where each table is in its own directory. There is no mechanism right now to make the snapshots appear to be in a single directory. You could probably whip up something with shell scripts and soft links, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup Cassandra directly to Tape using SPFS
SPFS is a file system for Spectrum Protect.

Just mount the SPFS file system where you want the backups to land.
Eg

## mount -t spfs /backup

And backup Cassandra to this path.

All operations that goes via this mountpoint (/backup), will automatically be translated to Spectrum Protect Client API calls.
On the Spectrum Protect backup server, one can use any type of supported media.
For instance: CD, Tape, VTL, SAS, SATA, SSD, Cloud etc..

In this way, you can easily backup your Cassandra directly to a backup server.